# How to get language locale of the user in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, localization

I am developing an application for Mac OS X. I want to change indication contents by the language locale (English, Spanish, etc.) of the application user, how do I get information of which language is used?

Answer (score 25):

```
NSLog(@"localeIdentifier: %@", [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]);
```

Comment: `[[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:[[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]]` can be used to get the plain-english version of the localeIdentifier

Answer (score 8):

You can use the NSLocale API to get that information, but it isn't necessary to do what you want to do. OS X has [support for localization](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html) built into the OS — all you need to do is supply the appropriate language files and the user can select which language he wants.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm happy , If you give me some example codes

Comment: It's not exactly the sort of thing where you can just give example code, since Mac user interfaces are usually stored in nibs and thus there isn't really any code responsible. Basically, there's a directory structure your app's resources need to follow and the OS will handle the rest for you. Read the localization docs in the link I gave you and you'll see how it works. For occasions where you are rendering text programmatically, you'll generally use the NSLocalizedString() function.

Answer (score 6):

code snippet

```
 NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale]; 
 [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode]
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use any way of both ways below:

```
NSString *language = [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier];
NSLog(@"Language: %@", language);
```

**output**: Language: en_US

or this:

```
NSString *language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"Language: %@", language);
```

**output**: Language: en

Answer (score 3):

You're looking to "localize" your application. To get started, check out the Apple docs here: [Internationalization - Apple Developer Docs](http://developer.apple.com/internationalization/localization/). Without knowing more about your specific application, it'd be hard to suggest anything more here!

Answer (score 0):

To be exact there is a change with iOS 9 and greater where [NSLocale preferredLanguages] now return - instead of only . So it's better to do:

```
NSString *languageOS = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];

if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 9.0) {
    languageOS = [[languageOS componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] objectAtIndex:0];
}
```