# Identifying user territory using Maps - Beginner

Tags: ios, mapkit

I have got into some trouble recently. My application is created for the use in UK. I have integrated maps to my application, and also i show the user's current location too.

If a particular user is using this application from USA, then i need to warn the user that this application is for the use in the UK. How could i do this programatically ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085506/how-to-get-language-locale-of-the-user-in-objective-c refer this link.

Comment: @ZunedAhmed Using language local to determine a user's current location is incorrect. I have people with Chinese language local using my app in Canada, not in China.

Answer (score 0):

1. Easy method: Don't dictate which country your users need to be in to use your app. I've developed an app local to the City of Calgary but released it world wide because if you're a tourist my app may be relevant.
2. Less Easy method: Jump on Google Maps, grab top-left lat/long of UK, grab bottom-right lat/long of UK, if user is outside bounding box, present them with a message.
3. Less Easy than "Less Easy" method: Do a lookup on the user's lat and long to get their current country. If not within a list of UK countries present them with a message.

Comment: In my application, i will be showing the distance from the user location to the nearest subway. So if the user is in US, then i can't show the distance to the nearest subway in UK. So what is the best solution i should adapt ?

Comment: @Illep figured there was a valid reason. I'd go with method #2 or #3 both are viable alternatives. Method #3 is going to be more accurate and method #2 is going to be easier to implement. You'll have to way the pros and cons based on your needs.