# How to determine current language on MacOS?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, localization, locale

I was able to determine current language on iOS with the following code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
NSString* language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] firstObject];
```

What is the equivalent for MacOS?

Note that I need not a region, but the language, so the following is not what I need:

```
NSLog(@"localeIdentifier: %@", [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085506/how-to-get-language-locale-of-the-user-in-objective-c

Comment: @Larme 'currentLocale' is the region, but not language

Comment: `[[NSLocale currentLocal] languageCode]` or `[NSLocale preferredLanguages]` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale/1415614-preferredlanguages?language=objc ?

Comment: @Larme no it is region language, but not selected language

Comment: but I figured out that `[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] firstObject]` also works, but I use `#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>`, but not `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`

Comment: @Larme or even `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`